# Hour format modification in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have Hour Column of pandas data frame in 0 to 23 format and AM and PM format,How can i convert to 00:00:00 to 23:00:00 format?

Format1:

```
Hour
0
2
13
15
17
18
23
```

Format 2:

```
Hour
12:00:00AM
2:00:00AM
1:00:00 PM
03:00:00PM
05:00:00PM
06:00:00PM
11:00:00PM
```

Desired Format

```
Hour
0:00:00
2:00:00
13:00:00
15:00:00
17:00:00
18:00:00
23:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your dataframe is named `df`

Format 1:

```
df.Hour = pd.to_datetime(df.Hour,format='%H').dt.time
```

Format 2:

```
df.Hour = pd.to_datetime(df.Hour).dt.time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['12:00:00AM','2:00:00AM','1:00:00PM','03:00:00PM','05:00:00PM','06:00:00PM','11:00:00PM']
b = map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x , '%I:%M:%S%p').strftime('%H:%M:%S'),a)
```